# Real solutions to the depressed cubic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, cubics

How can I find the allowed domain to this depressed cubic inequality

$$x^3 - 3 x + 2 \cos(\frac{3 \sqrt{3} n}{2}) \geq 0$$

where $n$ is a real non-negative number. Using Cardano's method, I can obtain some solutions for $x$ ($x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$) that should be real and not complex.

How can the solutions $x_j$ to define the feasible region satisfying the inequality for fixed $n$?

Comment: I was going to post an answer using Vieta's formulas, but it just gets us right back where we started.

Comment: Because cosine is bounded between $-1$ and $1$   you have three real roots. Cardano's method will show that, but you are in casus irreducibilis: despite real roots, Cardano's method will be using complex numbers explicitly. I'm not sure what you mean by the square brackets, but I don't see a rational  root for nonzero $n$  either

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=casus+irreducibilis  has many examples

Comment: I don't know if you like video materials but this by "mathologer" contains a good explanation with graphics etc. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-KXStupwsc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \frac{n\sqrt 3}{2}$.
Using $\cos 3\alpha = 4\cos^3 \alpha - 3 \cos \alpha$, the equation is written as
$$x^3 - 3x + 2(4\cos^3 \alpha - 3 \cos \alpha) = 0$$
or
$$(x^3 + (2\cos \alpha)^3) - 3(x + 2\cos \alpha) = 0$$
or
$$(x + 2\cos\alpha)(x^2 - 2x\cos\alpha + 4\cos^2\alpha - 3) = 0$$
or
$$(x + 2\cos\alpha)((x - \cos \alpha)^2 - 3\sin^2\alpha) = 0$$
or
$$(x + 2\cos\alpha)(x - \cos \alpha - \sqrt 3 \sin\alpha)(x - \cos \alpha + \sqrt 3\sin\alpha) = 0.$$
Thus, the roots are $x_1 = -2\cos \alpha, ~ x_2 = \cos \alpha + \sqrt 3 \sin\alpha, ~ x_3 = \cos \alpha - \sqrt 3 \sin \alpha$.

Note that $x_1 = x_2 = x_3$ implies
$\cos \alpha = \sin \alpha = 0$ which is impossible.

To find the domain, we need to sort $x_1, x_2, x_3$.
For example, if $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$,
then the allowed domain of $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)\ge 0$ is $[x_1, x_2]\cup [x_3, \infty)$;
if $x_1 = x_2 < x_3$, then the allowed domain is $[x_3, \infty)$.

Comment: The roots of this agree with what I obtained, but as in the OP how can I find the allowed domain for x? I.e. how can I use the roots to define the domain that satisfies the inequality for set $n$, which is a non-negative real number?

Comment: @Sid With the roots and the fact that the first term is $x^3$ you can get this very easily.

Comment: @SuzuHirose, one region is indeed easy to determine as the max of all roots. There should be another region that is harder to write but can be visualised.

Comment: @Sid Perhaps we need to sort $x_1, x_2, x_3$? I edited it.